# Не срабатывает оператор else. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

При выполнении лабораторной работы возникла вот такая проблема.
Первое поле задаёт нижнюю границу диапазона чисел, а второе - верхнюю. При введении числа в третье поле должен срабатывать ***if/else***.

В данном коде не срабатывает оператор ***else***, поэтому даже при выходе за заданный диапазон выдаётся сообщение о успешном вводе.

Что может быть не так? В упор не вижу проблему.

```
      var input = document.body.children[2];

      var minrange = document.getElementById('minrange').value;
      var maxrange = document.getElementById('maxrange').value;
      var integerEEE = document.getElementById('integer').value;

      input.oninput = function() {
               if (integerEEE >= minrange && integerEEE <= maxrange) {
                 alert("Введённое число входит в заданный диапазон. Валидация пройдена. Пожалуйста перезагрузите страницу и попробуйте снова.");
               }
             else {
               alert("Введённое число не входит в заданный диапазон. Пожалуйста перезагрузите страницу и попробуйте снова.");
             };
      };
    </script>
```

Comment: проблема в том, что значения переменных не меняются с момента сохранения, поэтому в обработчике всегда одни и те же значения проверяются. Судя по всему - пустые строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте определять значения input в момент когда срабатывает обработчик ивента

```
var input = document.body.children[2];

input.oninput = function() {

  var minrange = document.getElementById('minrange').value;
  var maxrange = document.getElementById('maxrange').value;
  var integerEEE = document.getElementById('integer').value;

  if (integerEEE >= minrange && integerEEE <= maxrange) {
    alert("Введённое число входит в заданный диапазон. Валидация пройдена. Пожалуйста перезагрузите страницу и попробуйте снова.");
  } else {
    alert("Введённое число не входит в заданный диапазон. Пожалуйста перезагрузите страницу и попробуйте снова.");
  };
};
```

Comment: "Семён Семёныч!"
Спасибо, затупил я конкретно.

Comment: @ДмитрийМарченков, и лучше все-таки перед сравнением в число перевести

Comment: @Grundy, т.е.. выглядеть будет примерно так?
`var minrange = document.getElementById('minrange').value.ToInteger;`

Comment: у строки нет свойства `ToInteger`, но можно использовать `parseInt`: `var minrange = parseInt(document.getElementById('minrange').value,10)`

Comment: @Grundy,Ага. Получается здесь мы передаём в parseInt значение нашего поля и задаём основание десятичной системы, на выходе получая целое число?

Comment: @ДмитрийМарченков, именно. Если нужно не целое число, то можно использовать `parseFloat` - эта функция принимает только один параметр.